# Erro mysql Duplicate entry ... for key "UNIQUE"

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde , estou com problemas em fazer update e inserir dados no meu banco mysql,
estou fazendo uma aplicação em php mas não estou conseguindo realizar essas ações de update e insert , segue imagem do codigo :

```js
$qry_mysqli = "SELECT
                    g.id_grupo,
                    g.descricao_grupo,
                CASE
                WHEN b.id_grupo IS NULL THEN 0
                AND g.descricao_grupo IS NOT NULL
                ELSE 1
                END status
                FROM
                    grupo g
                LEFT JOIN base_conhecimento_grupo b ON (
                            b.id_grupo = g.id_grupo
                AND b.id_base = $id
                AND b.data_baixa IS NULL
                )
                WHERE
                    g.ativo = 1
                    AND g.id_grupo IN ('".implode('\',\'',$lista_artigo)."')";


    //echo $qry_mysqli;
    //mysqli_rollback($conexao);
    //return;
                         
$result = mysqli_query($conexao,$qry_mysqli);

    //echo $qry_mysqli;
    //mysqli_rollback($conexao);
    //return;            

  

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

        if ($row->status == 1){ // checa para ver se o status está ativo com o valor 1
                    $qry_update = "UPDATE base_conhecimento_grupo 
                                    SET id_grupo = '$row->id_grupo' , data_cadastro= sysdate() 
                                    WHERE id_base = $id ";
        echo $qry_update;
        mysqli_rollback($conexao);
        
           
        mysqli_query($conexao , $qry_update) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
    
     }
    
    else{    //Realiza o incremento das informações no banco
        return;

                    $qry_inserir="  INSERT INTO 
                                    base_conhecimento_grupo (id_base,id_grupo,status,data_cadastro,id_usuario)
                                    VALUES
                                    ('$id','$row->id_grupo','1',sysdate(),'$id_usuario')";
                                    //echo $qry_inserir;
                                   // mysqli_rollback($conexao);                  
    }
                      mysqli_query($conexao,$qry_inserir) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));  
                   //  return;
                    
    }
```

Quando testo pelo console aparece essa mensagem:

> UPDATE base_conhecimento_grupo SET id_grupo = 'ADMTI' , data_cadastro=
>   sysdate() WHERE id_base = 2 Duplicate entry '2-ADMTI' for key 'UNIQUE'

e

> Duplicate entry '2-ADMLG' for key 'UNIQUE

Comment: a mensagem é bem clara, está inserindo um conteúdo duplicado ('2-ADMLG') num campo que está marcado como 'UNIQUE'

Comment: eu sei , tava querendo saber o que tenho que mudar no código para fazer ela não inserir o valor duplicado

Comment: ou você muda o q vem da variavel ou altera seu banco removendo a opção UNIQUE do campo em questão

Comment: precisa remover o unique o campo, pode mostrar a estrutura da tabela? agora se for um campo chave não vai dar para inserir duplicados